# Can I create Storage Attached Indexes on a map's values in Cassandra 4.x?

Tags: indexing, cassandra, cassandra-4.0

Is it be possible to create a Storage Attached Index on a map's values in Cassandra? In my case, I have a column named **coordinates** which is of data type `map<text,float>` and contains latitude and longitude of the sensors' locations. I would therefore like to create a **SAI** on the map's values so to be able to query the table based on those values.

Is this an anti-pattern? Would it be better to have two separate columns for latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, creating a SASI Index is not supported on a map (or other "complex" types) yet.

> Is this an anti-pattern?

Unfortunately yes.  Even if it worked, filtering in the `WHERE` clause by `coordinates` alone would not be a partition-based query, and would be a bit slow.  Not sure how the key is/was modeled here, but there would need to be some work done to ensure that a query could be served by a single node.  And SAI/SASI based index queries can't guarantee that.